# Passing Parameters from flex to database using java

Tags: java, apache-flex, postgresql, flex4, blazeds

I am facing one problem when am trying to insert values from flex(frontend) to database(backend).No problem in blazeds connection.I think problem is with java code.Anyway am pasting both java and flex code.Please let me know how to insert values into database.I am not well in java.So i tried a lot to solve this issue.

My Flex code is:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
        private function processSendFeedback():void
        {
            ro.getHelloByName(name_txt.text,email_txt.text,number_txt.text,fb_txt.text);
        }
        private function result(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(event.result));
        }
        private function fault(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(event.fault));
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:RemoteObject id="ro"
                    destination="helloworldname"
                    result="result(event)"
                    fault="fault(event)"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Panel x="176"
         y="112"
         width="414"
         height="325"
         title="FeedBack"
         borderColor="#008040"
         fontWeight="bold"
         fontSize="13">


    <s:Button label="Submit"
              id="senfeddback"
              click="processSendFeedback()" 
              x="178" 
              y="246" 
              height="22" 
              width="86" 
              cornerRadius="12"/>

    <s:Label x="61" y="38" text="Name"/>
    <s:Label x="61" y="72" text="Email"/>
    <s:Label x="61" y="105" text="Number"/>
    <s:Label x="50" y="142" text="Feedback"/>

    <s:TextInput id="name_txt" x="119" y="30" width="260"/>
    <s:TextInput id="email_txt" x="119" y="65" width="260"/>
    <s:TextInput id="number_txt" x="119" y="100" width="260"/>
    <s:TextInput id="fb_txt" x="119" y="134" width="260" height="104"/>

</s:Panel>
```

My Java Code is:

```
public class HelloWorldName 
{ 

public static void main(String[] argv) 
{
    System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL " +
            "JDBC Connection Testing ----------");
    getHelloByName(null, null, null, null);
}
public static String getHelloByName(String aName,String aMail,String aNumber,String aFeedback)
{
        String host = "localhost";
        String port = "1234";
        String dbName = "test";
        Connection connection = null;
    try 
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName,"postgres", "admin");

        System.out.println("Database is connected");    
     String strSQL = "insert into feedback(name,mobile_num,mail,feedback) values ('" + aName + "','" + aNumber +"','" + aMail +"','" + aFeedback +"')";
     Statement st = connection.createStatement();
     int a=st.executeUpdate(strSQL);
     System.out.println("hi,query executed");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    return "Hello from Java, " + aName + "," + aMail +"," + aNumber +"," + aFeedback +"";
}
}
```

I think i am sending null values in Main in java code.But if i try to add aName,aNumber,aMail,aFeedback in the place of null values error is showing.Is there any way to get solve this issue or is there any site to help to insert values into db using java,blazeds.Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you defined destination in remoting-config.xml in WEB-INF? Is there any error on console? please share

Comment: Yes Imran.I defined destination and it is displaying thae values whatever i entered in feedback form and it is displaying alert also.Problem is that it is not inserting into database.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is **JAVA static** method according to [Remoting Service](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html) definition

*The **Remoting Service** lets a client application access the **methods of server-side Java objects***

and in **java**/oops **static** methods are **not** associated to **Object**/instance its depends-upon/associated to class

your method should be like this to accept call from flex

```
public String getHelloByName(String aName,String aMail,String aNumber,String aFeedback)
```

and to call it in main(java main) use following lines

```
HelloWorldName helloWorldName = new HelloWorldName();
helloWorldName.getHelloByName(null, null, null, null);
```

Here is Flash-Builder BlazeDS-Remoting [sample](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder_blazeds.html)

hopes that works

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply Imran.I tried to follow your steps.But now also it is storing null values in the database.Whatever you sent the blazeds-remoting sample is not opening.I am getting 404 error.Please if you have an idea about these concepts let me know the steps in brief.

Comment: Link is working for me try an other "http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/using-flash-builder-4-for-earlier-blazeds-builds/", Are you sure BlazeDS is accessing Java method print some thing after function signature like public String getHelloByName(String aName,String aMail,String aNumber,String aFeedback){ System.out.printline("In getHelloByName"); //your code}, try this "In getHelloByName" should be print on server console

Comment: also change catch block as to print any exception on server                                catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }