# Passing Parameter from Flex to Java method which accepts datarecords or parametermap

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have developed java Program which will accept datarecords (function parameters) and will insert into database.But, I don't know how to pass parameters from flex to this Java Method.

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042076/passing-parameters-from-flex-to-database-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilties to communicate between flex and java. I recommend you take a look into the BlazeDS framework. There are a lot of tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Using RemoteObject components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/accessingdata/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fda.html)

For example:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"> 
    <fx:Declarations> 
        <mx:RemoteObject 
            id="userRequest" 
            destination="ColdFusion" 
            source="flexapp.returnusers"> 

            <mx:method name="returnRecords" result="returnHandler(event)" 
                       fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)"/> 
            <mx:method name="insertRecord" result="insertHandler()" 
                       fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)"/> 
        </mx:RemoteObject> 
    </fx:Declarations> 

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[ 
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent; 

            private function returnHandler(e:ResultEvent):void  
            { 
                dgUserRequest.dataProvider = e.result; 
            } 
            private function insertHandler():void  
            { 
                userRequest.returnRecords(); 
            } 
            private function clickHandler():void  
            { 
                userRequest.insertRecord(username.text, emailaddress.text); 
            }  
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script> 

    <mx:Form x="22" y="10" width="300"> 
        <mx:FormItem> 
            <s:Label text="Username" />     
            <s:TextInput id="username"/> 
        </mx:FormItem> 
        <mx:FormItem> 
            <s:Label text="Email Address" />     
            <s:TextInput id="emailaddress"/> 
        </mx:FormItem> 
        <s:Button label="Submit" click="clickHandler()"/> 
    </mx:Form> 

    <mx:DataGrid id="dgUserRequest" x="22" y="200"> 
        <mx:columns> 
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User ID" dataField="userid"/> 
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User Name" dataField="username"/> 
        </mx:columns> 
    </mx:DataGrid> 
</s:Application>
```

In return handler you receive e:ResultEvent and e.result contains result of your remote method call.

for

```
userRequest.returnRecords();
```

on java side will be

```
public List<User> returnRecords();
```